# apply opacity only on background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

first of all my problem is . i am coding a in parllex website in bootstrap i have putted a background image on section . but when i aplly opacity on it, the opacity apply on whole section but i don't want to . i just want opacity to be effective on image only but not on text and i have tried every solution on stack overflow which i can understand. plz help me out . my project deadlines are close. here is the code .

the section with id quotes here i have to apply the image . but don't want opacity on my text .

```
<!-- inpirational quotes
     ===================================================================== -->
  <section id="quotes" data-speed="10" data-type="background">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 section-heading animated"
                style="text-align:center" data-animation="fadeInUp" 
                data-animation-delay="0">
              <h2>Financial Services</h2>
              <h1>Dedicated to Creating the Best Mobile 
                  Financial Services Platform</h1>
              <p class="line">&nbsp;</p>
              <div class="quotes-p">
                 <div class="items">
                    <div class="text">Over 2.5 billion people globally are not 
                    supported by the traditional banking methods; they do not 
                    have access to a bank account. The good news is that these
                    people have mobile phones and in most cases all they need
                    to complete a financial transaction. It is also essential 
                    that people have a secure, safe, and seamless way to 
                    manage their cash which is First Global Data's strength.
                 </div>   
                 </div>
                 <div class="items">
                    <div class="text">LEADING EDGE TECHNOLOGY First Global has 
                    developed world class industry leading proprietary 
                    technology which allows the company to deliver a multitude 
                    of secure financial services such as International Money 
                    m Remittance, Loyalty and Rewards Programs.<br><br></div>

                 </div>
                 <div class="items">
                    <div class="text">First Global Money Inc., enables you to 
                    send money "At any Moment, From Anywhere, to Anyone Around 
                    the World”! <br><br><br><br></div>

                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </section>
```

the css goes here

```
#quotes {
color: #fff;
}
#quotes {
background-attachment: fixed;
background: url(../../img/parallax/1.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-y;
background-position: 50% 0;
background-size: cover;
}
#quotes h2 {
color: #FFF;
}
#quotes .line {
border-bottom-width: 2px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #fff;
margin-bottom: 30px;
width: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
#quotes .text {
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
}
#quotes .name {
color: #FFF;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: center;
font-style: italic;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `background:rgba();` method

Answer (score 1):

```
 background: url(../../img/parallax/1.jpg);
```

to

```
 background: url(../../img/parallax/1.jpg) rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

I have applied .3 on opacity, try this, but RGBA in IE, yes be careful.

Comment: You should also add `rgb(0,0,0)` for browsers that do not support the rgba.

Comment: hey i said , i tried everything . nothing is working . i again tried your method it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
filter:alpha(opacity=x); /* IE */
-moz-opacity:x; /* Mozilla */
opacity: x; /* CSS3 */
```

below

```
background: url(../../img/parallax/1.jpg);
```

Change x to wanted value.

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) link for more information

Comment: Not working bro . again the same problem it's fading the whole section .